# Can I use restful as website data service?

Tags: web-services, rest

90% information in website are static and updated by daily batch job. I am wondering I could use restful services for multi websites? If only 10% information is static, should I use it as well? Dose any body has used restful as data services for public website? My main website 's page view is round 10k/hour.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a little bit more information? I'm finding it hard to understand what you're asking here.

If you have any kind of structured data that you want to provide to external websites, REST is certainly a quick and easy way to do this.

If you know that the information changes only once a day, you could be caching the results of the REST GET requests on the external websites.

Comment: We have a centralized data hub for Asia. Now, we want to build public website for each country. The data in data hub will be updated by batch daily. And 90% information is static and not need maintain. However, we might update rest 10% data in data hub. We plan to use restful + xml + EHCache. One concern is that if restful + xml can handle 100tps? Is there any another object I can use?  If I use soap, I can use wsdl2java to generate domain object for me.